# Netlogo: Assigning parameter values from list of lists

Tags: list, netlogo, nested-lists

I'm stuck trying to process a list of lists in netlogo. Briefly, I'm working on a multi-species plant dispersal model. Each species has several parameters, the values of which can be changed during the simulation. I am trying to write a reporter that will iterate through a list of lists and assign the values to a given species. For example, here is the list of lists

```
[["Hi" 52] ["C" 0] ["Hc" 60] ["Hd" 1]]
```

Each species has an Hi, C, Hc, and Hd as part of their attributes, but the numbers vary. I cannot figure out how to iterate through the list of lists to do this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a foreach loop as below. I use run to set the variable's values.

```
let some-list [["Hi" 52] ["C" 0] ["Hc" 60] ["Hd" 1]]
foreach some-list
[
   let variable (first ?)
   let value (second ?)
   run (word "set " variable " " value)
]
```